# Activereports is divided url when it converting to PDF

Tags: activereports

I have RichTextBox with text with urls.

for exemple:

> Det er vigtigt at du l?ser vor Praktiske Information grundigt igennem
>   f?r afrejse. P? vores hjemmeside g?r du ind under ”Praktisk info” og
>   v?lger dit aktuelle rejsem?l.
>   https://www.example.com/watch?v=IjGNTqAW58E Her finder du mange
>   nyttige informationer omkring turen, s? som visum, vaccinationer,
>   bagage, transport  med mere. link til Praktisk Info

When I paste this text into report I find all urls and wrap it by tags:

```
richTextBox.RTF = richTextBox.RTF.Replace(url, @"{\field{\*\fldinst{ HYPERLINK " + $"\"{url}\"" + @"} }{\fldrslt{"+ $"{url}" +@" } } }\ul0\cf0");
```

In previewer it looks good the link is clickable and works right

But when I convert it to PDF it splits url in [two parts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4unX.png) when the string ends and the second path which in the second line is gone from url.

How to generate a PDF with a valid URL?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following format:
`"{\\field{\\*\\fldinst{ HYPERLINK "+"\"https://www.example.com/watch?v=IjGNTqAW58E\"" + "}}{\\fldrslt https://www.example.com/watch?v=IjGNTqAW58E}}"`

This keeps the url in one piece.

Comment: It works only previewer form but when I convert it to PDF it loses the part of URL
Picture: https://i.gyazo.com/21495e12efc53063ed19901920c3e55f.png

Comment: Could you please specify the version of Active Reports you are using?I tried to reproduce this issue on the latest build by exporting to PDF from Active Reports Viewer application but didn't observe such truncation: https://ibb.co/m8LnVF

Comment: As I see it is 9.4.4600.0

Comment: Unfortunately i'm unable to reproduce this issue at my side.Could you please share a link to a sample report file and describe steps to reproduce?